# R - Regression Analysis for Logarthmic

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I perform regression analysis and try to find the best fit model for the dataset diamonds.csv in `ggplot2`. I use price(response variable) vs carat and I perform linear regression, quadratic, and cubic regression. The line is not the best fit. I realize the logarithmic from excel has the best fitting line. However, I couldn't figure out how to code in R to find the logarithmic fitting line. Anyone can help?

## Comparing Price vs Carat

```
model<-lm(price~carat, data = diamonds)
```

## Model 2 uses the polynomial to compare

```
model2<-lm(price~carat + I(carat^2), data = diamonds)
```

## use cubic in model3

```
model3 <- lm(price~carat + I(carat^2) + I(carat^3), data = diamonds)
```

How can I code the log in R to get same result as excel?

y = 0.4299ln(x) - 2.5495
R² = 0.8468

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you report from excel `y = 0.4299ln(x) - 2.5495` does not contain any polynomial or cubic terms. What are you trying to do? `price` is very skewed and as with say 'income' it is common practice to take the log from that. This also provides the R2 you are referring to, but very different coefficients for the intercept and carat parameter.

```
m1 <- lm(log(price) ~ carat, data = diamonds)
summary(m1)
Call:
lm(formula = log(price) ~ carat, data = diamonds)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.2844 -0.2449  0.0335  0.2578  1.5642 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 6.215021   0.003348    1856   <2e-16 ***
carat       1.969757   0.003608     546   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.3972 on 53938 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8468,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8468 
F-statistic: 2.981e+05 on 1 and 53938 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: THANKS soo much for your help! I figure this out by your help. logmodel<- lm(price ~ log(carat), data = diamonds)
summary(logmodel)

Comment: Great! Not sure why you want the log of carat, but whatever suits your needs! Please upvote / accept the answer if you like it!

Comment: im new to this. where do i upvote and like your answer?

Comment: No worries, you can upvote by clicking on the triangle pointing upwards on the left hand side of my answer (just above the number zero) (and downvoting is done by clicking on the triangle pointing downwards). You should also see like a check mark icon (a v-shape, with a longer right leg). If you click that you would accept the answer as having the answered the question. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer